# Arduino - line follower car

Tags: arduino-uno

I want to build a line follower car, but I dont have Infrared sensors, so want to run the car, without sensors as a test

I have Motor Driver on top of Arduino UNO R3, all connections as expected, but all wheels are not spinning. I have no idea on which one is Motor1, 2,...

Code: https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/adamsstephen/controlling-an-l9100-motor-driver-board-using-arduino-cc5618#toc-step-1--placing-electronics-0

```
int Motor[8] ; // Array for all Motor Output pins, one more than required

void setup() {
  Motor[1] = 4; // Set output numbers for ports
  Motor[2] = 5;
  Motor[3] = 6;
  Motor[4] = 7;
  Motor[5] = 8;
  Motor[6] = 9; // Set up Port for LED on Head of Arm.
  Motor[7] = 10; // Forward / Reverse selection for ALL motors
  // Switch connected to GND and A0, to locally turn off motors while testing.
  pinMode(Motor[1], OUTPUT); // Open Port to operate Motor on Pincers Forward = In Reverse = Out
  pinMode(Motor[2], OUTPUT); // Open Port to operate Motor Up= High  Reverse = Down
  pinMode(Motor[3], OUTPUT); // Open Port to operate Motor Forward = Forward Reverse = Backward 
  pinMode(Motor[4], OUTPUT); // Open Port to operate Motor Wrist Forward = Up Reverse = Down
  pinMode(Motor[5], OUTPUT); // Open Port to operate Motor base Rotate Forward = Right Reverse = Left
  pinMode(Motor[6], OUTPUT); // Open Port to operate LED on head of Arm HIGH = ON LOW = OFF
  pinMode(Motor[7], OUTPUT); // Open Port for Forward / Reverse selection for ALL motors 
}
void loop() {
    digitalWrite(Motor[6], LOW); // Turn off LED.
    if (analogRead(A0)< 1){ // switch ON
    digitalWrite(Motor[1], HIGH); // Turn on Motor 1. HIGH turns it on! Pincers
    digitalWrite(Motor[7], LOW); // HIGH is Forward, Reverse is OFF.
   Serial.println(analogRead(A0));
}
    if (analogRead(A0) > 200  ){    // switch OFF
    digitalWrite(Motor[1], LOW); // Turn on Motor 1. HIGH turns it on!
    digitalWrite(Motor[7], LOW); // HIGH is Forward, Reverse is OFF.
   Serial.println(analogRead(A0));
}
    delay(200); // debounce the switch action
}
```

I commented the whole loop(), still some wheels are spinning. how is that possible? How can I know - which one is Motor1 ,...M4 and the corresponding Arduino pin numbers. 
I want to spin all 4 wheels/ dc motors

Comment: Welcome to Arduino Stack Exchange. Please edit your question with add your schematics

Comment: why are you trying to control seven motors when you have trouble controlling one? ... reduce your sketch so that it controls only one motor ... figure out which pin you are controlling with your sketch and connect the motor to that pin .... when you get that working, then change to a different pin (edit the sketch) ... keep going until you tested all seven output pins using only one motor ... then try to run two motors  .... etc. etc.

Comment: @jsotola I have no idea, that is why I am here. I commented all lines except - PinMode Motor[4] and 3 wheels are spinning. It is literally 1 lines of code and 3 wheels spinning. One time same code - only 1 wheel spinning. So I am seeking for an expert to give a useful answer. thanks

Comment: Try to grounds all pinout motors exception one motor wire opened at 7404 chip. That's @jsotola means

Comment: no, that is not what I mean ... remove all motors ... remove all wires ... connect one motor ... connect only the wires necessary to run the one motor ... run a simple sketch that turns on the motor, pauses for 2 seconds, turns off the motor ... do not put any code in loop() ... put all code in setup()

Comment: Apologies, but the interface to me is the motor driver - Motor Driver Shield L293D. which I think supports 4 wheels [has M1/2/3/4], is placed on top of Uno R3. So, I do not know underlying Arduino  pins. Note: I am connecting via USB and testing, hoping that it has enough voltage. Cant believe how this 1 line -  pinMode(Motor[4], OUTPUT);  is spinning 2 wheels and my head too.

Comment: L9100 or l293d is same to me, you can try jsotola suggest. That's very helpful and provide us more informative with add your schematic

Comment: Looks like it is voltage issue. the car has, 4 dual shift motors. supplied 2 x 18650 and 3 wheels spinning, sometimes 4. sometimes 1, sometimes 2, sometimes all 4, sometimes only 1 in reverse. Inconsistent results. Not sure how much power needs to be supplied. Do dual shaft  require double the  single shaft ?